# Как сделать такой слайдер через slick?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать такой слайдер через slick ?
справа слайдер, слева превью 
[image: слайдер]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для блока из вертикальных превью используйте свойство [`vertical: true`](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#settings), а для синхронизации слайдеров есть свойства `Slider Syncing`, на офф. сайте slick уже есть готовый пример, вам просто нужно добавить `vertical: true`.